# loading CSS with cdi

Tags: javascript, java, php, codeigniter, assets

I'm using codeigniter4 my project is about children's education, I'm trying to set the template, I make all the steps to load assets to my project, but it's not working.

1. In my `codeigniter4`, I don't have **config** file on `codeigniter4/app/config`.
2. In **autoload.php**, I have this line `public $helpers = [];`
3. In **constant.php**, I add these lines:

```php
defined('css')      || define('css', 'https://localhost/codeigniter4/public/css'); 
defined('images')      || define('css', 'https://localhost/codeigniter4/public/images'); 
and at the end of the file, I add these lines:
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
defined('BASE') || define('BASE',$protocol);
```

4. my **base_url** is `https://localhost/codeigniter4` so I turn in **app.php** this line:

```php
public string $baseURL = BASE;
```

5. the main problem for me is that in **index.php**, I put the correct code base_url like this for example:

```html
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js');?>"></script>
```

How can I load assets?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: In `config.php` add these lines, see if works:

`$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;`

Comment: I have only one config.php => codeigniter4/system/config/config.php

but it didn't work with your lines :(